# Height of a spherical cap from volume and radius

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, spheres

$\hskip 2.2 in$[image]

I'm trying to calculate the height of a spherical cap on a sphere where you know the volume of the cap and the radius of the sphere.

I was able to find the equation for the volume of the cap with radius $r$ and height $h$ which is

$$V=\frac{\pi h^2}{3}(3r-h)$$

I feel really dumb but for the life of me I can't seem to rewrite the equation in such a way to find $h$ when given a known volume and radius.

Comment: It is a cubic equation in $h$ and it took a couple of hundred years for somebody to come up with a formula, so I would not feel too bad about it if I were you. Also the formula is pretty complicated, so if you are given numbers for $r, V$ and want to solve for $h$, you'd probably use some sort of successive approximation method to solve it. Any "Numerical methods" book would provide a number of these to consider.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the reassurance.
It's actually in a program I'm writing so how complicated the formula is isn't terribly important. That being said I ended up using a completely different method which was less accurate but more helpful to the actual users.

Answer (score 2):

You have to solve the cubic
$$
\frac{\pi}{3}h^3-\pi r h^2+V=0
$$

that always have a real solution for $h$, and, in general, can be solved with  [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to solve for the height algebraically, you could solve for the height by graphing the equation and finding the x-intercepts. This can be done on a graphing calculator or online at [Desmos Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Graph the equation
$$
\frac{\pi}{3}h^2\ (3r - h) - V
$$
and locate the x-intercepts

Answer (score 1):

By solving the volume formula $[V=\frac{\pi h^2}{3}(3r-h)]$ for h to obtain the cubic equation $[\frac{\pi}{3}h^3-\pi r h^2+V=0]$, converting to the depressed cubic form of the equation $[t^3+pt+q]$, using the trigonometric solution $\Bigg[\Bigg(t_k=2\sqrt{-\frac{p}{3}}\cos\bigg[\frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}}\bigg)-\frac{2\pi k}{3}\bigg]\Bigg)$ for $k=0,1,2\Bigg]$ to solve for the root where k=1, converting back to the original form of the cubic equation, and simplifying, the following solution can be obtained for h in terms of V and r.

$$
h=r[\sqrt{3}\sin(\frac{1}{3}cos^{-1}A)-\cos(\frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}A)+1]
$$
$$
A=1-\frac{3V}{2\pi r^3}=1-\frac{2V}{V_{sphere}}
$$

Answer (score -1):

Given $V$ in order to find $h$ we have to find roots of the cubic equation.

EDIT1:

It is more convenient to express given volume as a fraction$f$ of the full sphere$ \;4\pi r^3/3$

$$\dfrac{\pi h^2(3r-h)}{3}=f \dfrac43 \pi r^3 \;\;\rightarrow 4fr^3+h^3-3r h^2=0$$

The following is given by `Mathematica` for $h$ value.

```
  Solve[-3 r h^2 + h^3 + 4 f r^3 == 0, h]
```

$$ \left(r+\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{f^2 r^6-f r^6}-2 f r^3+r^3}+\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) r^2}{2 \sqrt[3]{2 \sqrt{f^2 r^6-f r^6}-2 f r^3+r^3}}\right)
$$

in which the imaginary part cancels on evaluation.

Else if you want a graphic solution read off $h$ for given $ (V,r)$  or vice-versa as shown:

[image]