# Height of spherical cap contained inside a spherical cap

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, spheres

I have a sphere of radius $r$, whose spherical cap has a height $h$:

[image: Spherical cap]

Say I have the volume $V$ of another spherical cap (on the same sphere), whose height is $h_2<h$ (just to make this more interesting, say water filling a spherical pond to some height).

I wish to express $h_2$ as a function of $V$ and $r$. In a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364343/height-of-a-spherical-cap-from-volume-and-radius), the solution was given in the form of a cubic equation, which I understand. Plugging this equation [into Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%2F3%20*%20h%5E3%20-%20pi%20*%20r%20*h%5E2%2BV%20%3D0%20for%20h) gives an expression with a term,

$$ \sqrt{3V^2-4 \pi r^3 V} $$

where again $V$ is the (given) volume of the spherical cap and $r$ is the radius of the sphere. Taking out $3V$ (positive by definition) from the radical we get,

$$ \sqrt{3V}\sqrt{V-\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3} $$

which will always be complex if the volume of the sphere is greater than the volume in question. I may be missing something, but I don't understand how that's possible (how can we distribute a volume greater than a volume of the sphere in a fraction of that sphere...?) - I assume I just have a mistake somewhere. Would be great to get reprimanded as long as I figure this out... :-). Thanks.

Comment: if you were to divide $\sqrt{3V^2 -4\pi r^3V}$ by $3V$, you are actually dividing it by $\sqrt{9V^2}$.

Comment: So that surd has to become the denominator of the expression, i.e., $\sqrt{\frac{3V^2 - 4\pi r^3V}{9V^2}}$.

Comment: I meant the expression inside the radical. Anyway, this is not important here, I think, as the expression you wrote down is still complex for all V, r where $V < 4/3 \pi r^3$. E.g., re-write my expression as $\sqrt{3V}\sqrt{V-4/3\pi r^3}$ and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: maybe you should be right, if $3V^2 > 4\pi r^3V$.

Comment: $V$ is the volume of the actual sphere (the sphere of which the caps are part of), right ?

Comment: But since $V > 0$, that can be reduced to $V>4/3 \pi r^3$, right? 

To your second question: V is the volume of the smaller spherical cap.

Comment: I think yes now... Thanks

Comment: Sorry ! I erred : the third comment I put was wrong.. somebody please correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized what's wrong (just in case someone Googles it in the future).

The answer contains two complex numbers whose imaginary parts cancel one another, making the total answer a real number.